# Is "la luna en el cielo de Oregon" grammatically correct?

Tags: gramática

I would like to know if the phrase, "la luna en el cielo de Oregon" is correct.  This is part of a gift and I want to be absolutely sure it is grammatically correct.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add more context to the sentence. It is grammatically correct but so is "la luna de Oregón".

Comment: It is the title of a photo that I took.

Comment: Then the title is perfect for me. Just remember to write "Oregón", with the ó.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see anything ungrammatical in that sentence. However, it may or may not make sense depending on the context. If you are talking about the Moon shining in the sky above Oregon, then it is probably fine.

Comment: Yes.  That is exactly what I mean.  I will add more context to future questions. Thanks to all who answered.